# Uploading a buffer to google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, gcloud-node

I'm trying to save a Buffer (of a file uploaded from a form) to Google Cloud storage, but it seems like the Google Node SDK only allows files with a given path to be uploaded (Read / Write streams).

This is what I have used for AWS (S3) - is the anything else similar in the Google node SDK?:

```
var fileContents = new Buffer('buffer');

var params = {
  Bucket: //bucket name
  Key: //file name
  ContentType: // Set mimetype
  Body: fileContents 
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
// Do something 
});
```

The only way that I have found to do it so far is write the buffer to disk, upload the file using the SDK (specifying the path to the new file) and then delete the file once it's uploaded successfully - the downside to this is that the whole process is **significantly** slower, to where it seems to be unfeasible to use Google storage. Is there any work around / way to upload a buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have an issue about supporting this more easily: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/1179

But for now, you can try:

```
file.createWriteStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('finish', function() {})
  .end(fileContents);
```

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, the cloud storage package now supports `.save` which does exactly what you're asking: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save

Answer (score 28):

`.save` to save the day! Some code below where I save my "pdf" that I created.

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const gc = new Storage({
  keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, "./path to your service account .json"),
  projectId: "your project id",
});

      const file = gc.bucket(bucketName).file("tester.pdf");
      file.save(pdf, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("cool");
        } else {
          console.log("error " + err);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 10):

This is actually easy:

```
  let remotePath = 'some/key/to/store.json';
  let localReadStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  localReadStream.end(JSON.stringify(someObject, null, '   '));

  let remoteWriteStream = bucket.file(remotePath).createWriteStream({ 
     metadata : { 
        contentType : 'application/json' 
     }
  });

  localReadStream.pipe(remoteWriteStream)
  .on('error', err => {
     return callback(err);      
  })
  .on('finish', () => {
     return callback();
  });
```

Comment: Please elaborate the answer.

Comment: `const stream = require('stream');` is missing

Comment: Where's the multer in-menory buffer object in this example?

Comment: remote path Slashes will get replaced by underscores and no "folder" will be created.

Answer (score 6):

The following snippet is from a google example. The example assumes you have used multer, or something similar, and can access the file at `req.file`. You can stream the file to cloud storage using middleware that resembles the following:

```
function sendUploadToGCS (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const gcsname = Date.now() + req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });

  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish', () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
      next();
    });
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
```

Comment: Where is getPublicUrl() function

Answer (score 5):

I have this approach working to me:

```
const destFileName = `someFolder/${file.name}`;
const fileCloud = this.storage.bucket(bucketName).file(destFileName);
    fileCloud.save(file.buffer, {
        contentType: file.mimetype
     }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log("error");
     }
});
```